# Reverse proxy onto a WordPress page?

Tags: php, wordpress

so there's this website where I don't currently have access to anything except admin access on WordPress. Is it possible to have a custom page which can serve content from another server like a reverse proxy?

ie. I'm WordPress admin at `blog.xyz.com`, and I have another server at IP `a.b.c.d`, which I control. I want users to go to `blog.xyz.com/someurl` and see the content that `a.b.c.d` serves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Server setup**

Before you even touch WordPress, you need to make sure that the server hosting B is ready to accept requests and forward requests for any URL to A.

Assuming you have Apache setup and working, let’s make sure mod_proxy is enabled. With root or sudo privileges, run:

```
a2enmod proxy_http
service apache2 restart
```

Then, open the Apache virtual hosts config file, and add:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off   
<Location /blog>
    ProxyPass http://blog.mysite.com 
    ProxyPassReverse http://blog.mysite.com  
    Order allow,deny   
     Allow from all
</Location>
```

Now you got to make sure that all URLs (category pages, single post pages) also display correctly on site B.

For this, log into WordPress admin using the original login link: blog.mysite.com/wp-login.php.

Go to `Settings > General`, and update the `“Site address (URL)”` field to B `(supersite.com/blog)`.

Credits : https://tanyanam.com/2015/07/13/setting-up-wordpress-behind-reverse-proxy/

Comment: If mod_proxy is activated, you can also use mod_rewrite to proxy your requests with something like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [P,L]`